# Scala: Can multiple json check be in single check?

Tags: json, scala, gatling

I am new in scala programming, please consider the scenario...

```
.exec(http("request_7")
.post("/test/listing")
.headers(headers_12)
.formParam("abcId", "${abcID}")     
.formParam("action_id", "100")
.formParam("controller", "/test/listing")
.check(jsonPath("$.data[*].xyzId").findAll.saveAs("xyzID"))
.check(jsonPath("$.data[*].abcNo").findAll.saveAs("ABCNo"))
.check(jsonPath("$.data[*].revId").findAll.saveAs("revID"))
.check(jsonPath("$.data[*].dTypeId").findAll.saveAs("dTypeID")))
```

In this request, I have to implement multiple check(s) to get the value. It is manual procedure.
Is there any method in scala to perform this scenario in single check? In other words,
I want to get these values in single json check. Is it possible???

So can anyone tell me what is the method to implement this scenario???

Your help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Praveen Mourya

Comment: thanks, Sudhir Singh. Let me tell you one thing that, I am getting all values from same address. So, Is it possible to get multiple values from single json check?

Comment: Hi All,
Issue is reolved.
By: 

.check(
      jsonPath("$.data[*].xyzId").findAll.saveAs("xyzID"),
      jsonPath("$.data[*].abcNo").findAll.saveAs("ABCNo"),...
      ...and so on
    )

thanks.